# Can't access post or get from a php page after redirecting

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I'am redirecting about 100 hmtl pages to a single PHP page (example.php) using .htaccess. It is working perfectly.

I've pagination on that page (example.php) but I am using the original HTML page URL (example.html?page=2&limit=20)

1. so example.html, example1.html, example2.html, example3.html are all redirecting to example.php.
2. The address bar is still showing  ".html" URL but due to .htaccess redirection the example.php is rendering.
3. when is click on a pagination link (example.html?page=2&limit=20) the browser address bar shows correct .html URL and query string.
4. I've tried to get the values of  page, and limit using $_GET and $_REQUEST in (example.php) but i am not successful.

Please help me in reading the (example.html?page=2&limit=20) query string parameeters .

**Edit** Code ported from comments:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^page-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)$ size-content.php?sef=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please post your code! We need to see the .htaccess Rewrite rules.

Comment: Most likely, you are missing a `[QSA]` flag.

Comment: HERE is the .htaccess code RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^page-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)$ size-content.php?sef=$1 [L]

Answer (score 3):

Add the QSA flag, which means "query-string append" to be sure the existing query string is ported into the rewritten URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^page-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)$ size-content.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess modify your server configuration.

if you are making redirection then you change your request.
Try mod_rewrite if you are using Apache of course.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example\.html\?(.*) example.php?$1
```

Mod rewrite is module to Apache. It is not allowed on most free hostings.

Answer (score 0):

Yasir - you can resolve this problem by two ways:
1) Re-write rules for .htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^page-(.*).html(.*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^page-(.*).html(.*)/(.*)$ size-content.php?sef=$1&page=$2&limit=$3 [L]

This rule will handle: page-example.html?page=2&limit=20

I hope - you will easily understand the above rule.

Note: Keep one thing in your mind that every link should be in same pattern if you change rule in htaccess.

2) You can resolve this problem on your "size-content.php"

Suppose page-example.html?page=2&limit=20

$_GET['sef'] = example.html?page=2&limit=20 [according to you .htaccess]

Now you can parse this string via explode function

Thanks